# Java: Java5 enum custom serialization

Tags: java, serialization, enums

For serializing large enum instances, I was thinking of using a "serialization proxy" where the proxy object would be a very small object uniquely identifying the corresponding enum instance. However I found out that any read/writeObject or resolve/replace methods are ignored for enums. So my question is, how would I efficiently serialize large enum instances? A String/XML representation is a possibility, but my feeling is this would be a maintenance issue.

Comment: `enum` identifiers are only sent once per stream. Are you sure this is a big problem for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reinventing what is already done by default by the Java serialization:

Quote from 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/relnotes15.html:

> Support has been added to serialization to handle enumerated types,
>   which are new in version 5.0. The rules for serializing an enum
>   instance differ from those for serializing an "ordinary" serializable
>   object: the serialized form of an enum instance consists only of its
>   enum constant name, along with information identifying its base enum
>   type. Deserialization behavior differs as well--the class information
>   is used to find the appropriate enum class, and the Enum.valueOf
>   method is called with that class and the received constant name in
>   order to obtain the enum constant to return.